# How to make my modal slide down in React using keyframes

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a modal sliding up fine in React using keyframes. I want it to slide down when closing. The slide up is triggered by a state and I am trying to trigger the slide down by setting the class to happen when the user clicks to close the button.

Not sure how to achieve this with keyframes.

Here is my code:

`JSX`

```
  <div
        className={classnames(styles.modal, {
            [styles.toDisplayModal]: showModal,
            [styles.toCloseModal]: closeModal,
        })}
    >
            <div className={styles.container}>
                    <CloseButton onClick={closeModal} />
                   <div> text </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

`CSS modules & Key frames`

```
.toDisplayModal{
    margin: auto;
    top: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
    animation: slideup 0.3s;
}

.toCloseModal {
    animation: slidedown 0.3s;
}

@keyframes slideup {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(400px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(20px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    80% {
        transform: translateY(10px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
}
@keyframes slidedown {
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    80% {
        transform: translateY(10px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(20px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    0% {
        transform: translateY(400px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
```

}
}

Comment: `slidedown` animation should start from 0%.

Comment: tried that and didn't work, in fact adds an odd behavior which is a jump of the modal on click to open

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`.

```css
.toDisplayModal{
    margin: auto;
    top: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    animation: slidedown 0.3s 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes slidedown {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(10px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    80% {
        transform: translateY(20px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(400px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="toDisplayModal">
    Modal
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the first part of `.toDisplayModal` needs to be put inside `.modal` because this is the part responsible for showing the modal.

```
{
    margin: auto;
    top: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
}
```

because you want the modal to be shown when it slides down.